# Neovim colorscheme applying differently

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, colorscheme

I am trying to get this [darkplus colorscheme](https://github.com/martinsione/darkplus.nvim) to apply correctly in my neovim setup but the colors are off completely. When I run `:colorscheme` it returns `default` and when I run the command `:colorscheme default` the colors change. I believe some of the the `darkplus` theme is being applyed however not completely. I have my Konsole profile environment set to `TERM=xterm-256color`.

Here is my current colors:

[partial color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2Fjm.jpg)

Here is the desired colors:

[desired color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KSlg.jpg)

I am not too sure how the VIM syntax highlighting and colors work together, do I just not have the right syntax highlighting specifications?

Here is my `init.vim`:

```
" PLUGINS
call plug#begin(expand('\~/.config/nvim/plugged'))
Plug 'sheerun/vim-polyglot'
Plug 'voldikss/vim-floaterm'
Plug 'tpope/vim-commentary'
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'
Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plug 'Raimondi/delimitMate'
Plug 'majutsushi/tagbar'
Plug 'Yggdroot/indentLine'
Plug 'tpope/vim-rhubarb' " required by fugitive to :Gbrowse
Plug '907th/vim-auto-save'
Plug 'neoclide/coc.nvim', {'branch': 'release'}
Plug 'cdelledonne/vim-cmake'
Plug 'alepez/vim-gtest'
Plug 'martinsione/darkplus.nvim'
Plug 'antoinemadec/FixCursorHold.nvim'
Plug 'dart-lang/dart-vim-plugin'

if isdirectory('/usr/local/opt/fzf')
Plug '/usr/local/opt/fzf' | Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
else
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'dir': '\~/.fzf', 'do': './install --bin' }
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
endif
let g:make = 'gmake'
if exists('make')
let g:make = 'make'
endif
Plug 'honza/vim-snippets'
Plug 'gko/vim-coloresque'
Plug 'mattn/emmet-vim'
call plug#end()

" CUSTOM CONFIG
" \~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~
"
" Abbreviations
cnoreabbrev W! w!
cnoreabbrev Q! q!
cnoreabbrev Qall! qall!
cnoreabbrev Wq wq
cnoreabbrev Wa wa
cnoreabbrev wQ wq
cnoreabbrev WQ wq
cnoreabbrev W w
cnoreabbrev Q q
cnoreabbrev Qall qall

" Vanilla Neovim
set encoding=utf-8
set mouse=a
syntax on
set number
let mapleader = ","
let g:python_host_prog = '/usr/bin/python3'
set background=dark
colorscheme darkplus
inoremap \\ \<ESC\> :!
nnoremap \\ :!
inoremap jj \<ESC\>
nmap \<leader\>\<tab\> \<c-w\>w
nmap \<c-s\> :w\<CR\>
imap \<c-s\> \<Esc\>:w\<CR\>a
set grepprg=ag\\ --nogroup\\ --nocolor

" floaterm
let g:floaterm_keymap_new = '\<Leader\>ft'
let g:floaterm_keymap_toggle = '\<Leader\>t'
nmap \<c-t\> :FloatermNew fff\<cr\>

" FZF
let $FZF_DEFAULT_COMMAND = 'ag --hidden --ignore node_modules -U -g ""'
nnoremap \<Leader\>e :Files\<Cr\>

" vim-airline
let g:NERDTreeWinSize = 50

" vim-airline-themes
let g:airline_theme = 'term'

" vim-auto-save
let g:auto_save_events = \["InsertLeave", "TextChanged"\]
let g:auto_save = 1

"\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~
" coc.nvim
" Some servers have issues with backup files, see #649.
set nobackup
set nowritebackup

" Having longer updatetime (default is 4000 ms = 4 s) leads to noticeable
" delays and poor user experience.
set updatetime=300

" Always show the signcolumn, otherwise it would shift the text each time
" diagnostics appear/become resolved.
set signcolumn=yes

" Use tab for trigger completion with characters ahead and navigate.
" NOTE: There's always complete item selected by default, you may want to enable
" no select by `"suggest.noselect": true` in your configuration file.
" NOTE: Use command ':verbose imap \<tab\>' to make sure tab is not mapped by
" other plugin before putting this into your config.
inoremap \<silent\>\<expr\> \<TAB\>
\\ coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#next(1) :
\\ CheckBackspace() ? "\<Tab\>" :
\\ coc#refresh()
inoremap \<expr\>\<S-TAB\> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#prev(1) : "\<C-h\>"

" Make \<CR\> to accept selected completion item or notify coc.nvim to format
" \<C-g\>u breaks current undo, please make your own choice.
inoremap \<silent\>\<expr\> \<CR\> coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#confirm()
: "\<C-g\>u\<CR\>\<c-r\>=coc#on_enter()\<CR\>"

function! CheckBackspace() abort
let col = col('.') - 1
return !col || getline('.')\[col - 1\]  =\~# '\\s'
endfunction

" Use \<c-space\> to trigger completion.
if has('nvim')
inoremap \<silent\>\<expr\> \<c-space\> coc#refresh()
else
inoremap \<silent\>\<expr\> \<c-@\> coc#refresh()
endif

" Use `[g` and `]g` to navigate diagnostics
" Use `:CocDiagnostics` to get all diagnostics of current buffer in location list.
nmap \<silent\> \[g \<Plug\>(coc-diagnostic-prev)
nmap \<silent\> \]g \<Plug\>(coc-diagnostic-next)

" GoTo code navigation.
nmap \<silent\> gd \<Plug\>(coc-definition)
nmap \<silent\> gy \<Plug\>(coc-type-definition)
nmap \<silent\> gi \<Plug\>(coc-implementation)
nmap \<silent\> gr \<Plug\>(coc-references)

" Use K to show documentation in preview window.
nnoremap \<silent\> K :call ShowDocumentation()\<CR\>

function! ShowDocumentation()
if CocAction('hasProvider', 'hover')
call CocActionAsync('doHover')
else
call feedkeys('K', 'in')
endif
endfunction

" Highlight the symbol and its references when holding the cursor.
autocmd CursorHold \* silent call CocActionAsync('highlight')

" Symbol renaming.
nmap \<leader\>rn \<Plug\>(coc-rename)

" Formatting selected code.
xmap \<leader\>f  \<Plug\>(coc-format-selected)
nmap \<leader\>f  \<Plug\>(coc-format-selected)

augroup mygroup
autocmd!
" Setup formatexpr specified filetype(s).
autocmd FileType typescript,json setl formatexpr=CocAction('formatSelected')
" Update signature help on jump placeholder.
autocmd User CocJumpPlaceholder call CocActionAsync('showSignatureHelp')
augroup end

" Applying codeAction to the selected region.
" Example: `<leader>aap` for current paragraph
xmap \<leader\>a  \<Plug\>(coc-codeaction-selected)
nmap \<leader\>a  \<Plug\>(coc-codeaction-selected)

" Remap keys for applying codeAction to the current buffer.
nmap \<leader\>ac  \<Plug\>(coc-codeaction)
" Apply AutoFix to problem on the current line.
nmap \<leader\>qf  \<Plug\>(coc-fix-current)

" Run the Code Lens action on the current line.
nmap \<leader\>cl  \<Plug\>(coc-codelens-action)

" Map function and class text objects
" NOTE: Requires 'textDocument.documentSymbol' support from the language server.
xmap if \<Plug\>(coc-funcobj-i)
omap if \<Plug\>(coc-funcobj-i)
xmap af \<Plug\>(coc-funcobj-a)
omap af \<Plug\>(coc-funcobj-a)
xmap ic \<Plug\>(coc-classobj-i)
omap ic \<Plug\>(coc-classobj-i)
xmap ac \<Plug\>(coc-classobj-a)
omap ac \<Plug\>(coc-classobj-a)

" Remap \<C-f\> and \<C-b\> for scroll float windows/popups.
if has('nvim-0.4.0') || has('patch-8.2.0750')
nnoremap \<silent\>\<nowait\>\<expr\> \<C-f\> coc#float#has_scroll() ? coc#float#scroll(1) : "\<C-f\>"
nnoremap \<silent\>\<nowait\>\<expr\> \<C-b\> coc#float#has_scroll() ? coc#float#scroll(0) : "\<C-b\>"
inoremap \<silent\>\<nowait\>\<expr\> \<C-f\> coc#float#has_scroll() ? "\<c-r\>=coc#float#scroll(1)\<cr\>" : "\<Right\>"
inoremap \<silent\>\<nowait\>\<expr\> \<C-b\> coc#float#has_scroll() ? "\<c-r\>=coc#float#scroll(0)\<cr\>" : "\<Left\>"
vnorema \<silent\>\<nowait\>\<expr\> \<C-f\> coc#float#has_scroll() ? coc#float#scroll(1) : "\<C-f\>"
vnoremap \<silent\>\<nowait\>\<expr\> \<C-b\> coc#float#has_scroll() ? coc#float#scroll(0) : "\<C-b\>"
endif

" Use CTRL-S for selections ranges.
" Requires 'textDocument/selectionRange' support of language server.
nmap \<silent\> \<C-s\> \<Plug\>(coc-range-select)
xmap \<silent\> \<C-s\> \<Plug\>(coc-range-select)

" Add `:Format` command to format current buffer.
command! -nargs=0 Format :call CocActionAsync('format')

" Add `:Fold` command to fold current buffer.
command! -nargs=? Fold :call     CocAction('fold', \<f-args\>)

" Add `:OR` command for organize imports of the current buffer.
command! -nargs=0 OR   :call     CocActionAsync('runCommand', 'editor.action.organizeImport')

" Add (Neo)Vim's native statusline support.
" NOTE: Please see `:h coc-status` for integrations with external plugins that
" provide custom statusline: lightline.vim, vim-airline.
set statusline^=%{coc#status()}%{get(b:,'coc_current_function','')}

" Mappings for CoCList
" Show all diagnostics.
nnoremap \<silent\>\<nowait\> \<space\>a  :\<C-u\>CocList diagnostics\<cr\>
" Manage extensions.
nnoremap \<silent\>\<nowait\> \<space\>e  :\<C-u\>CocList extensions\<cr\>
" Show commands.
nnoremap \<silent\>\<nowait\> \<space\>c  :\<C-u\>CocList commands\<cr\>
" Find symbol of current document.
nnoremap \<silent\>\<nowait\> \<space\>o  :\<C-u\>CocList outline\<cr\>
" Search workspace symbols.
nnoremap \<silent\>\<nowait\> \<space\>s  :\<C-u\>CocList -I symbols\<cr\>
" Do default action for next item.
nnoremap \<silent\>\<nowait\> \<space\>j  :\<C-u\>CocNext\<CR\>
" Do default action for previous item.
nnoremap \<silent\>\<nowait\> \<space\>k  :\<C-u\>CocPrev\<CR\>
" Resume latest coc list.
nnoremap \<silent\>\<nowait\> \<space\>p  :\<C-u\>CocListResume\<CR\>p
"\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~

" vim-cmake
let g:cmake_link_compile_commands = 1
nmap \<leader\>cg :CMakeGenerate\<cr\>
nmap \<leader\>cb :CMakeBuild\<cr\>

" vim-gtest
" let g:gtest#gtest_command WILL UPDATE THIS AT LATER TIME
nmap \<leader\>gt :GTestRunUnderCursor\<cr\>

" dart-vim-plugin
let g:dart_style_guide = 2

" emmet-vim
let g:user_emmet_leader_key='\<leader\>'
```

I have tried changing different konsole profiles and reseting the syntax multiple times with no luck.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Try to get a _minimal_ vimrc that reproduces the error. For example, you might try [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Comment: FWIW I'm having the same issue with that specific theme as well (other themes work fine and :colorscheme returns the correct value).